# CakePHP TreeBehavior::recover() SQL error

Tags: cakephp, tree, cakephp-2.3

So I'm trying to use the recover method of the TreeBehavior, as I think some of my data is corrupted.  When trying to do this, I get this SQL error:

Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND' at line 1
SQL Query: UPDATE `fracmerl_dev`.`categories` AS `Category` SET `Category`.`lft` = `Category`.`lft` + 4203 WHERE `Category`.`lft` BETWEEN AND

Obviously the query is missing some values.  I also get this warning:

Notice (8): Undefined offset: 0 [CORE/Cake/Model/Behavior/TreeBehavior.php, line 865]

This is Cake version 2.3.

Edit:

Line 865 in TreeBehavior is the last line in this block of code:

```
        list($node) = array_values($Model->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array($scope, $Model->escapeField() => $Model->id),
        'fields' => array($Model->primaryKey, $parent, $left, $right),
        'recursive' => $recursive
    ))); //THIS IS LINE 865
```

So I'm assuming the return value of `array_values($Model->find...` does not have an offset `0`. Seems weird that PHP is telling me the error is on that line, rather than line 861, but I've double checked and that's definitely the line.

Thanks

Comment: if it's version 2.3 - why have you tagged it cakephp-2.0 :P? line 865 of the tree behavior [does not point at a line of code which can produce the undefined offset error](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.3.0/lib/Cake/Model/Behavior/TreeBehavior.php#L865). The undefined offset error is key, as that's where the numeric values for the between come from.

Comment: Well, 2.0 is the closest available tag :).  I have updated my question with some more info

Comment: Actually it looks like my line 865 is different to the one on that link - I may have altered the line numbers by trying to debug stuff from that file.  To be clear, the line in my question commented "THIS IS LINE 865" is my line 865 :)

Comment: I think you've got some other behaviors or functionality interfering - that query is trying to find the record that was immediately-before saved and is not finding it. Look at the sql query that it's generating and determine why it does not find the record with the given primary key to continue. As is this isn't a question that can simply be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AD7six was right and there was something interfering.  I had a `beforeFind()` callback in my model which looked like this:

```
public function beforeFind($queryData){
    if ((!isset($queryData['exclude']) || $queryData['exclude']) && (empty($queryData['conditions']['Category.id']) || is_array($queryData['conditions']['Category.id']))){
        $queryData['conditions'][] = array('NOT' => array('Category.id' => $this->exclude));
    }
    return $queryData;
}
```

This callback was preventing TreeBehavior from finding the item that it wanted to find to carry on sorting out the data.